# Scrape "paginasamarillas.es" using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape

Hi I using scrapy for scrape paginasamarillas.es but I don't get results these are my codes.Please can you help me with this?

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class AyellItem(Item):
name = Field()
pass
```

This is the spider

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ayell.items import AyellItem

    class YellSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'yell'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.paginasamarillas.es']
    start_urls = ['http://www.paginasamarillas.es/alimentacion/all-ma/all-pr/all-is/all-ci/all-ba/all-pu/all-nc/1']



    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        directors = hxs.select("/html/body")
        items = []
        for directors in directors:
            item = AyellItem()
            item ["name"] = directors.select("/h1").extract()   
            items.append(item)
            return items
```

and this what i get

> 2015-07-31 19:11:25-0300 [yell] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.paginasamarillas.es/alimentacion/all-ma/all-pr/all-is/all-ci/all-ba/all-pu/all-nc/1>
>   (referer: None)
>       2015-07-31 19:11:25-0300 [yell] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
>       2015-07-31 19:11:25-0300 [yell] INFO: Dumping spider stats:   {'downloader/request_bytes': 267,    'downloader/request_count': 1,
>   'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
>   'downloader/response_bytes': 30509,    'downloader/response_count': 1,
>      'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,      'finish_reason':
>   'finished',    'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 31, 22, 11,
>   25, 731485),   'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 1,

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like this is a new spider.  If you're able to, I'd recommend updating to Scrapy 1.0.1 instead of staying with 0.24 (or lower).

`AyellItem` has an indentation error, though this may just be how you typed it into SO.  Additionally, there's no purpose for your `pass`.

As for the spider itself, there are a few notable issues:

- You're not specifying any rules.  The spider will not process any links after retrieving the first page.
- You're not parsing the content of the first page.  In order to do so, you need to override the `parse_start_url(response)` method.
- You're XPath selectors don't work for the provided page.  There is only one `<h1>` element on the page, and it is not at `/html/body/h1`.  The items you want are list items (`<li>`'s) nested within a div with the class "contenido"

Reading up on the [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider), [Scrapy Selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#selectors), and overall familiarize yourself better with the technologies you're using should help you out.  Best of luck!